# SVG sprite and viewbox property

Tags: svg, sprite

I am trying to create a SVG sprite and to understand how it works.

As I was looking for an example on the Internet, I found this one:
https://codepen.io/jnettik/pen/GRqmbvv
from this website: https://atendesigngroup.com/articles/svg-sprites-embed-flexible-stylable-fast-loading-svg-icons

Let's consider the first icon (email).
On the one hand, we have:

```
<symbol id="icon--mail" viewBox="0 0 241.061 241.061">
```

and on the other hand, we have:

```
<svg class="svg--icon icon--mail" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
```

Also, from the `svg--icon` CSS class, we can see that the width of the svg is set to `40px`.

I tried:

- to remove `viewBox="0 0 24 24"`.
  If I do, the email icon is put into a rectangle that is approximately five times its height.
- to change `viewBox="0 0 24 24"` to `viewBox="0 0 1 1"` or `viewBox="0 0 10000 10000"`.
  I doesn't change anything.

Can you explain why:

- we end up with two `viewbox` properties per SVG, why one is not enough, what is the purpose of each,
- these values (`0 0 24 24`) have been chosen,
- what do the values `241.061 241.061` correspond to?

I post the code below.
Can someone correct that code by writing the proper viewbox properties values in such a way I understand how it works?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>SVG sprite viewbox</title>
    
        <style>
            *
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            
            img, svg
            {
                border: 0;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                display: block;
            }
        
            .visually-hidden {
            display: none;
            }
    
            svg {
            fill: currentColor;
            }
    
            .svg--icons {
            background-color: palegreen;
            }

            .svg--icon {
            border: solid 1px black;
            }

            .icon--mail {
            color: blue;
            }
    
            .icon--phone {
            color: green;
            }
    
            .icon--location {
            color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="svg--icons">
            <svg class="svg--icon icon--mail" width="40px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <use xlink:href="#icon--mail" />
            </svg>
          
            <svg class="svg--icon icon--phone" width="40px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <use xlink:href="#icon--phone" />
            </svg>
          
            <svg class="svg--icon icon--location" width="40px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <use xlink:href="#icon--location" />
            </svg>
        </div>
            
        <div class="visually-hidden">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            
                <symbol id="icon--mail" viewBox="0 0 241.061 241.061">
                    <path d="M198.602,70.402l-78.063,68.789l-78.08-68.79c-3.109-2.739-7.848-2.438-10.586,0.669c-2.737,3.108-2.439,7.847,0.67,10.586l83.039,73.159c1.417,1.248,3.188,1.872,4.958,1.872s3.542-0.624,4.959-1.873l83.022-73.159c3.107-2.738,3.406-7.478,0.668-10.586C206.449,67.964,201.711,67.664,198.602,70.402z"/>
                    <path d="M218.561,38.529H22.5c-12.406,0-22.5,10.093-22.5,22.5v119.002c0,12.407,10.094,22.5,22.5,22.5h196.061c12.406,0,22.5-10.093,22.5-22.5V61.029C241.061,48.623,230.967,38.529,218.561,38.529z M226.061,180.031c0,4.135-3.364,7.5-7.5,7.5H22.5c-4.136,0-7.5-3.365-7.5-7.5V61.029c0-4.135,3.364-7.5,7.5-7.5h196.061c4.136,0,7.5,3.365,7.5,7.5V180.031z"/>
                </symbol>
            
                <symbol id="icon--phone" viewBox="0 0 211.621 211.621">
                    <path d="M180.948,27.722C163.07,9.844,139.299-0.001,114.017,0c-4.143,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5c0,4.142,3.358,7.5,7.5,7.5c21.276-0.001,41.279,8.284,56.324,23.329c15.046,15.045,23.331,35.049,23.33,56.326c0,4.142,3.357,7.5,7.5,7.5c4.142,0,7.5-3.358,7.5-7.499C208.672,69.371,198.827,45.6,180.948,27.722z"/>
                    <path d="M150.096,94.656c0,4.142,3.358,7.5,7.501,7.499c4.142,0,7.499-3.358,7.499-7.5c-0.002-28.16-22.916-51.073-51.078-51.077c-0.001,0,0,0-0.001,0c-4.142,0-7.499,3.357-7.5,7.499c0,4.142,3.357,7.5,7.499,7.501C133.909,58.581,150.094,74.765,150.096,94.656z"/>
                    <path d="M133.5,132.896c-11.432-0.592-17.256,7.91-20.049,11.994c-2.339,3.419-1.463,8.086,1.956,10.425c3.419,2.339,8.086,1.463,10.425-1.956c3.3-4.825,4.795-5.584,6.823-5.488c6.491,0.763,32.056,19.497,34.616,25.355c0.642,1.725,0.618,3.416-0.071,5.473c-2.684,7.966-7.127,13.564-12.851,16.188c-5.438,2.493-12.105,2.267-19.276-0.651c-26.777-10.914-50.171-26.145-69.531-45.271c-0.008-0.008-0.016-0.015-0.023-0.023c-19.086-19.341-34.289-42.705-45.185-69.441c-2.919-7.177-3.145-13.845-0.652-19.282c2.624-5.724,8.222-10.167,16.181-12.848c2.064-0.692,3.752-0.714,5.461-0.078c5.879,2.569,24.612,28.133,25.368,34.551c0.108,2.104-0.657,3.598-5.478,6.892c-3.42,2.336-4.299,7.003-1.962,10.423c2.336,3.42,7.002,4.298,10.423,1.962c4.086-2.79,12.586-8.598,11.996-20.069C81.021,69.07,57.713,37.339,46.576,33.244c-4.953-1.846-10.163-1.878-15.491-0.09C19.097,37.191,10.439,44.389,6.047,53.969c-4.26,9.294-4.125,20.077,0.395,31.189c11.661,28.612,27.976,53.647,48.491,74.412c0.05,0.051,0.101,0.101,0.153,0.15c20.75,20.477,45.756,36.762,74.33,48.409c5.722,2.327,11.357,3.492,16.746,3.492c5.074,0,9.932-1.032,14.438-3.098c9.581-4.391,16.778-13.048,20.818-25.044c1.784-5.318,1.755-10.526-0.077-15.456C177.232,156.856,145.501,133.548,133.5,132.896z"/>
                </symbol>
                
                <symbol id="icon--location" viewBox="0 0 217.109 217.109">
                    <path d="M108.552,0C62.42,0,24.89,37.535,24.89,83.672c0,32.967,13.802,66.314,39.914,96.437c19.503,22.499,38.831,35.246,39.645,35.778c1.246,0.815,2.675,1.222,4.104,1.222c1.428,0,2.857-0.407,4.104-1.222c0.813-0.532,20.144-13.279,39.647-35.777c26.114-30.124,39.917-63.471,39.917-96.438C192.22,37.535,154.686,0,108.552,0z M108.552,200.4C93.165,188.934,39.89,144.806,39.89,83.672C39.89,45.806,70.691,15,108.552,15c37.864,0,68.668,30.806,68.668,68.672C177.22,144.806,123.94,188.934,108.552,200.4z"/>
                    <path d="M108.557,50.449c-18.31,0-33.206,14.897-33.206,33.209c0,18.307,14.896,33.201,33.206,33.201c18.31,0,33.205-14.894,33.205-33.201C141.762,65.347,126.866,50.449,108.557,50.449z M108.557,101.859c-10.039,0-18.206-8.165-18.206-18.201c0-10.041,8.167-18.209,18.206-18.209c10.038,0,18.205,8.168,18.205,18.209C126.762,93.694,118.595,101.859,108.557,101.859z"/>
                </symbol>
            
            </svg>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I removed two SVG images out of three.
I removed the `viewBox="0 0 24 24"` property from the `svg` element where it was initially.
I moved the `viewbox` property that was inside the `symbol` element inside that `svg` element.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>SVG sprite viewbox</title>
    
        <style>
            *
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            
            img, svg
            {
                border: 0;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                display: block;
            }
        
            .visually-hidden {
            display: none;
            }
    
            svg {
            fill: currentColor;
            }
    
            .svg--icons {
            background-color: palegreen;
            }
            .svg--icon {
            border: solid 1px black;
            }
            .icon--phone {
            color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="svg--icons">
            <svg class="svg--icon icon--phone" width="100px" viewBox="0 0 211.621 211.621">
                <use xlink:href="#icon--phone" />
            </svg>                
        </div>
            
        <div class="visually-hidden">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            
                <symbol id="icon--phone">
                    <path d="M180.948,27.722C163.07,9.844,139.299-0.001,114.017,0c-4.143,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5c0,4.142,3.358,7.5,7.5,7.5c21.276-0.001,41.279,8.284,56.324,23.329c15.046,15.045,23.331,35.049,23.33,56.326c0,4.142,3.357,7.5,7.5,7.5c4.142,0,7.5-3.358,7.5-7.499C208.672,69.371,198.827,45.6,180.948,27.722z"/>
                    <path d="M150.096,94.656c0,4.142,3.358,7.5,7.501,7.499c4.142,0,7.499-3.358,7.499-7.5c-0.002-28.16-22.916-51.073-51.078-51.077c-0.001,0,0,0-0.001,0c-4.142,0-7.499,3.357-7.5,7.499c0,4.142,3.357,7.5,7.499,7.501C133.909,58.581,150.094,74.765,150.096,94.656z"/>
                    <path d="M133.5,132.896c-11.432-0.592-17.256,7.91-20.049,11.994c-2.339,3.419-1.463,8.086,1.956,10.425c3.419,2.339,8.086,1.463,10.425-1.956c3.3-4.825,4.795-5.584,6.823-5.488c6.491,0.763,32.056,19.497,34.616,25.355c0.642,1.725,0.618,3.416-0.071,5.473c-2.684,7.966-7.127,13.564-12.851,16.188c-5.438,2.493-12.105,2.267-19.276-0.651c-26.777-10.914-50.171-26.145-69.531-45.271c-0.008-0.008-0.016-0.015-0.023-0.023c-19.086-19.341-34.289-42.705-45.185-69.441c-2.919-7.177-3.145-13.845-0.652-19.282c2.624-5.724,8.222-10.167,16.181-12.848c2.064-0.692,3.752-0.714,5.461-0.078c5.879,2.569,24.612,28.133,25.368,34.551c0.108,2.104-0.657,3.598-5.478,6.892c-3.42,2.336-4.299,7.003-1.962,10.423c2.336,3.42,7.002,4.298,10.423,1.962c4.086-2.79,12.586-8.598,11.996-20.069C81.021,69.07,57.713,37.339,46.576,33.244c-4.953-1.846-10.163-1.878-15.491-0.09C19.097,37.191,10.439,44.389,6.047,53.969c-4.26,9.294-4.125,20.077,0.395,31.189c11.661,28.612,27.976,53.647,48.491,74.412c0.05,0.051,0.101,0.101,0.153,0.15c20.75,20.477,45.756,36.762,74.33,48.409c5.722,2.327,11.357,3.492,16.746,3.492c5.074,0,9.932-1.032,14.438-3.098c9.581-4.391,16.778-13.048,20.818-25.044c1.784-5.318,1.755-10.526-0.077-15.456C177.232,156.856,145.501,133.548,133.5,132.896z"/>
                </symbol>
            
            </svg>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was trying to explain what the values (`211.621`, `211.621`) exactly are...
Here is my try:
The values (`211.621`, `211.621`) are the values that ensure the SVG image (whatever its width in pixels may be) can be seen in its entirety at the size that corresponds to the chosen dimensions, perfectly centered, with no padding.

I created a SVG sprite file which contents are:

```
<svg width="0" height="0" fill="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" aria-hidden="true">
    <symbol id="icon--phone">
        <path d="M180.948,27.722C163.07,9.844,139.299-0.001,114.017,0c-4.143,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5c0,4.142,3.358,7.5,7.5,7.5c21.276-0.001,41.279,8.284,56.324,23.329c15.046,15.045,23.331,35.049,23.33,56.326c0,4.142,3.357,7.5,7.5,7.5c4.142,0,7.5-3.358,7.5-7.499C208.672,69.371,198.827,45.6,180.948,27.722z"/>
        <path d="M150.096,94.656c0,4.142,3.358,7.5,7.501,7.499c4.142,0,7.499-3.358,7.499-7.5c-0.002-28.16-22.916-51.073-51.078-51.077c-0.001,0,0,0-0.001,0c-4.142,0-7.499,3.357-7.5,7.499c0,4.142,3.357,7.5,7.499,7.501C133.909,58.581,150.094,74.765,150.096,94.656z"/>
        <path d="M133.5,132.896c-11.432-0.592-17.256,7.91-20.049,11.994c-2.339,3.419-1.463,8.086,1.956,10.425c3.419,2.339,8.086,1.463,10.425-1.956c3.3-4.825,4.795-5.584,6.823-5.488c6.491,0.763,32.056,19.497,34.616,25.355c0.642,1.725,0.618,3.416-0.071,5.473c-2.684,7.966-7.127,13.564-12.851,16.188c-5.438,2.493-12.105,2.267-19.276-0.651c-26.777-10.914-50.171-26.145-69.531-45.271c-0.008-0.008-0.016-0.015-0.023-0.023c-19.086-19.341-34.289-42.705-45.185-69.441c-2.919-7.177-3.145-13.845-0.652-19.282c2.624-5.724,8.222-10.167,16.181-12.848c2.064-0.692,3.752-0.714,5.461-0.078c5.879,2.569,24.612,28.133,25.368,34.551c0.108,2.104-0.657,3.598-5.478,6.892c-3.42,2.336-4.299,7.003-1.962,10.423c2.336,3.42,7.002,4.298,10.423,1.962c4.086-2.79,12.586-8.598,11.996-20.069C81.021,69.07,57.713,37.339,46.576,33.244c-4.953-1.846-10.163-1.878-15.491-0.09C19.097,37.191,10.439,44.389,6.047,53.969c-4.26,9.294-4.125,20.077,0.395,31.189c11.661,28.612,27.976,53.647,48.491,74.412c0.05,0.051,0.101,0.101,0.153,0.15c20.75,20.477,45.756,36.762,74.33,48.409c5.722,2.327,11.357,3.492,16.746,3.492c5.074,0,9.932-1.032,14.438-3.098c9.581-4.391,16.778-13.048,20.818-25.044c1.784-5.318,1.755-10.526-0.077-15.456C177.232,156.856,145.501,133.548,133.5,132.896z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

I modified the HTML code accordingly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Z4</title>
    
        <style>
            *
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            
            img, svg
            {
                border: 0;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                display: block;
            }
        
            .visually-hidden {
            display: none;
            }
    
            svg {
            fill: currentColor;
            }
    
            .svg--icons {
            background-color: palegreen;
            }
            .svg--icon {
            border: solid 1px black;
            }
            .icon--phone {
            color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="svg--icons">
            <svg class="svg--icon icon--phone" width="100px" viewBox="0 0 211.621 211.621">
                    <use xlink:href="svg/svg_sprite_example.svg#icon--phone" />
                </svg>                
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

When I visit the HTML page, the image doesn't appear.
Can you see what's wrong?

I added the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` attribute to the `svg` element in the external file and that solves the problem mentioned above.

Comment: Try a ``viewBox="0 0 10 10`` and then a ``viewBox="0 0 20 20``, and deduce what happened. ``241.061`` is a designer who doesn't understand SVG and probably used an Adobe tool to resize an icon

Comment: Hi. I tried. It doesn't change a thing, does it?

Comment: You are making it too complex, learning 3 viewBox atonce, start with one see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/svg-svg-viewbox

Comment: @LéaMassiot no namespaces so the external file is invalid.

Comment: Please do not add comments saying you edited the post. Just make sure the current version of the question is the most up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to explain here. First of all if we leave out the viewBox, width and height attributes of an SVG it will get the default size of 300x150. This can cheat a bit, so keep that in mind. Here is an example:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="orange"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

If we introduce the viewBox attribute on this simple SVG, you can see that there is no difference between using `0 0 100 100` and `0 0 10 10`. That is because the SVG will always try to take up as much space as possible -- it is 100% in width by default (except for the first example). That is why you experience that it doesn't matter what you write in the viewBox, it looks the same (now, that the content (`<use>` in you case) also will fill up the container). Two examples with different viewBox values and one just to show what happens when we give the SVG a width:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="orange"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="MediumSeaGreen"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="160">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="Coral"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Now to the question about the symbol. In the case of the symbol (and in general SVG elements) the viewBox attribute is used for defining the inner coordinate system. So the size of the viewBox needs to fit the size of the elements that are inside that element with the viewBox attribute. Here are two examples with the same path element. It fits the first SVG, not the second:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M 5 5 H 95 C 75 40 75 60 95 95 C 40 95 5 50 5 5" fill="orange"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <path d="M 5 5 H 95 C 75 40 75 60 95 95 C 40 95 5 50 5 5" fill="MediumSeaGreen"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

So, now we can combine it all. You have a symbol width a viewBox attribute and no width and height. Thus, it will always fill up the container element, in your case the SVG element that contains the use element. The value of the viewBox for the symbol reflects the size of the contained shapes.

So, in this specific situation the viewBox defined for the SVG can have arbitrary numbers (as long as you keep to the right aspect ratio). That is the following first example. If you specify width and/or height for either the symbol or the SVG element this can "mess up" something. Often it is a good idea to just to leave them out and let some CSS for containing elements control the sizes. If on the other hand you remove the viewBox attribute, the inner coordinate system will start to reflect the context. This is what happens in the second example where the shape will be 90px in width, because the numbers in the path are now corresponding to the pixel size in the HTML page.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
    <use href="#S01"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use href="#S02"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0"
  style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">
  <symbol id="S01" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M 5 5 H 95 C 75 40 75 60 95 95 C 40 95 5 50 5 5" fill="orange"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="S02">
    <path d="M 5 5 H 95 C 75 40 75 60 95 95 C 40 95 5 50 5 5" fill="MediumSeaGreen"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```